# woocommerce add custom fee from meta and multiple by meta value coming from gravity forms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin

ok so this is my code so far, i am able to set my custom fee in each product via custom field, everything is displaying correctly in the cart. Now I need to be able to multiply it by the value from a dropdown field coming from gravity forms plugin. i have the woocommerce gravity forms addon.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge');
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
global $woocommerce;
if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;
//Loop through the cart to find out the extra costs
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    //Get the product info
    $_product = $values['data'];


    //Get the custom field value
    $custom_fee = get_post_meta($_product->id, 'taxes_fees', true);


    //Adding together the extra costs
    $extra_custom_fee = $extra_custom_fee + $custom_fee;
}

//Lets check if we actually have a fee, then add it
if ($extra_custom_fee) {$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Taxes & Fees', $extra_custom_fee, true, 'standard' )* $field["choices"][0]["value"];
}}
```

simple example

```
$fee="20";
adult=2
child=2
$var1=adult+child=4
$fee*$var1="80"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got my answer from a friend, i'll post it here just in case someone may need it someday. My site is an activity site, i have custom fields where i input a fee, i have gravity form fields with an "inputname" which is the css and dynamic name. i get those names(from gravity's api) and get the value, explode everything and take the number and multiply it by the fee on each product.

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge');
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge()
{
global $woocommerce;
if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) return;

$extra_custom_fee = 0;

//Loop through the cart to find out the extra costs
foreach ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {

    //Get the product info
    $_product = $values['data'];

    // Find ID's for Adults and Kids charge in Gravity Form
    $form = GFAPI::get_form($values['_gravity_form_data']['id']);

    $total_adults = 0;
    $total_kids = 0;

    foreach ($form['fields'] as $field) {
        if ($field['inputName'] == 'adultsprice' &&
            !empty($values['_gravity_form_lead'][$field['id']])) {
            $parts = explode('|', $values['_gravity_form_lead'][$field['id']]);
            if (count($parts) == 2) {
                $total_adults = intval($parts[0]);
                $total_adult_charge = doubleval($parts[1]);
            }
        }
        else if ($field['inputName'] == 'kidsprice' &&
            !empty($values['_gravity_form_lead'][$field['id']])) {
            $parts = explode('|', $values['_gravity_form_lead'][$field['id']]);
            if (count($parts) == 2) {
                $total_kids = intval($parts[0]);
                $total_kids_charge = doubleval($parts[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    //Get the custom field value
    $custom_fee = intval(get_post_meta($_product->id, 'taxes_fees', true));

    //Adding together the extra costs
    $extra_custom_fee += $custom_fee * ($total_adults + $total_kids);

}

//Lets check if we actually have a fee, then add it
if ($extra_custom_fee > 0) {
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('Taxes & Fees', $extra_custom_fee, true, 'standard');
}
}
```